# Animate a single figure

Tags: java, animation

I can't understand how to animate a single figure in Java applet, while the context remains the same (for example rotate a polygon while other figures drawn remain the same).

Is there another solution besides repainting the object and the whole context?  I am asking because it would be hard to have for example a number of figures that would need to be animated when clicked.

Could you please point me towards the topics I need to understand, as well maybe an example to see things more clearly?

Comment: *"I can't understand how to ... in Java applet"*  You'd do it in a Java applet exactly the same way you'd do it in an application.  Or to put that another way.  This has nothing to do with applets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology you want is *[sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29)*. There's a short intro video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKGpBl3D0v0) and you can search the web for oodles of info about implementing them in Java.